# FLAC - How to decode to terminal

Tags: linux, audio, flac

I know how to decode my flac audio file into a wav, like this:
`flac -d flac.flac wav.wav`, which converts flac.flac to wav.wav. But, I want to write the wav data to the terminal, so that I can pipe it to another program without needing to save it to a file. For, example, I want to do something like this `flac_to_wav_output_terminal | cat > /path/to/wav/file` (that command is not what I am going to do exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix programs don't "write to the terminal", if you want to pipe their output to another program, the term is **stdout** (short for *standard output*), which is the name of the file descriptor used internally. In the same way, they read from **stdin** (or *standard input*).

So if you look at the manpage (`man flac`), and search for the term `stdout` (with the `less` pager, you can use `/` to search), you'll see the following:

```
   -c, --stdout
             Write output to stdout
```

Therefore `flac -c -d flac.wav | ...` will do what you want.

Also note that in your example

```
flac_to_wav_output_terminal | cat > /path/to/wav/file
```

the `cat` is superflous, as you could have written

```
flac_to_wav_output_terminal > /path/to/wav/file
```